# How to determine the block device booted from in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell-scripting, block-device

I'm crafting up a shell script (to be called by cron) that runs smartctl on the booted disk on a weekly basis. Is there a fairly universal way to determine what the boot block device is (IE - /dev/sda, /dev/hdb, etc)? The expected install would be standard, I think I could get away with using grep " / " on /etc/fstab, I'm just wondering if there's a more graceful way.

This script will specifically be deployed on Fedora and possibly Ubuntu boxes.

Comment: Are you really looking for the boot device, or are you looking for the root device?  If you are looking for / in fstab, and your boot device is different from your root device then you may not get the results you want.

Comment: That is a valid point. For my specific needs, it will always be the same device.

Comment: What boot-loader are you using on these machines?

Comment: Grub currently, but the best solution should be future-proofed against alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

`df -P / | tail -n 1 | awk '/.*/ { print $1 }'`

Will return the root FS block device. Not necessarily the boot device though.

Better question might be why you're not scanning SMART on all the disks in the server?

Comment: In my specific case, this is a script that will be deployed to hundreds of single-disk kiosk machines with either a SATA or PATA disk (so 99% of them would be /dev/sda or /dev/hda, I just want to make sure I don't miss the 1% that somehow ended up being /dev/sdb or something). Your solution almost works. Unfortunately, what I need is the boot device (That returns /dev/sda3, I just need /dev/sda).

Answer (score 1):

for /boot:

readlink -f /dev/block/$(mountpoint -d /boot)

for rootfs:

readlink -f /dev/block/$(mountpoint -d /)

Explanation:
1) mountpoint -d 
 - gives major:minor numbers of device mounted at

2) /dev/block folder
- contains symlinks os all block devices by device numbers pointing back to regular device file in /dev

3) readlink -f 
- reconstruct device name from sym link

Works on all modern Linuxes

Comment: This needs an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /proc/mounts |grep /boot |awk '{print $1}'
```

Will return something like /dev/sda1 if your /boot is not on the root device.
Combine this with the answer from Chris S.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably long since moved on from this task, but I was trying to do something similar and figured I'd look into the missing piece of your puzzle, namely to get the drive designation (e.g. `/dev/sda`) instead of the partition designation (e.g. `/dev/sda1`).

I started off with [Chris S's excellent answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/339100/how-to-determine-the-block-device-booted-from-in-a-shell-script#answer-339107) (which also solved the task I was seeking to accomplish), and then just used good old fashioned bash string manipulation to trim the number off the end (leaving you with the drive vs the partition):

```
# first, save the output (e.g. /dev/sda1) to a variable
rootpart=$(df -P / | tail -n 1 | awk '/.*/ { print $1 }')

# now you can trim the number off:
echo ${rootpart//[[:digit:]]/}

# if ${rootpart} was "/dev/sda1", output would be "/dev/sda"
```